# Adding to select orderby or sortby filtering on search result Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

How do I add on select orderby sorting on search result please?

[image] laravel 5.8?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not use screenshots unless strictly necessary. Put the code in text format and use formatting tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK based on your comment I've updated my answer:

on the front end the select menu should update the url with the selected menu item, you can use a onchange to do this:

```
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
    <option value="">Sort By</option>
    <option value="?sortBy=rate" {{ (request('sortBy') == 'rate' ? 'selected=selected' : '') }}>Rate</option>
    <option value="?sortBy=popular" {{ (request('sortBy') == 'popular' ? 'selected=selected' : '') }}>Popular</option>
    <option value="?sortBy=ohirgi" {{ (request('sortBy') == 'ohirgi' ? 'selected=selected' : '') }}>Ohirgi</option>
    <option value="?sortBy=id" {{ (request('sortBy') == 'id' ? 'selected=selected' : '') }}>id</option>
</select>
```

When selected will add ?sortBy= and the option selected to the url. or ?sortBy=rate

write your query but leave off the ->get() then you can chain additional options on when complete then terminate with ->get() or ->paginate()

```
//initial query without terminator
$doctors = Doctor_list::where('speciality_title', 'LIKE', '%'.$key.'%');

//if there is a sort request use it, otherwise use the default sort
switch (request('sortBy')) {
case 'rate':
    $doctors->orderby('rate', 'desc');
    break;
case 'Popular':
    $doctors->orderby('popular', 'asc');
    break;
case 'Ohirgi':
    $doctors->orderby('ohirgi', 'asc');
    break;
default:
    $doctors->orderby('id', 'asc');
    break;
}

//complete the query and terminate it with paginate or ->get()
$doctors = $doctors->paginate();
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, unfortunately it's sorting by deafult. I was about selecting on blade then get sorted. I've tried to add some like this: controller If ($request->get('sortBy') === 'rate'){
            dd($doctors->orderBy('rate', 'desc'));
        }  on select I've added.   <select name="sortBy" class="select">
          <option>tanlang</option>
          <option class="sorting" value="rate}">rate</option>
          <option class="sorting">Popular</option>
          <option class="sorting">Ohirgi</option>
         </select>     but no luck. I'm not sure whats wrong.

Comment: I've changed my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate it. Search result giving as before but select section still same doesn't work. I think I need to call select even  with jquery /ajax to make this result happen. Any thoughts?

Comment: ajax is not needed but a form submission is needed for this to work or pass in query strings on page load.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm new here I'm not sure how to add a snippet on comments. Do you mean I have to add form tag to <select name="sortBy" class="select"> ?

Comment: yes in order for the request() to have access to a selected sortBy item, the item needs to be sent to the server so the controller can read it. 

what I do is add a onchange event to the select <select onchange="location = this.value;"> I'll update my answer

Comment: thanks for this Dave, you've saved my life. Now after sorting resetting search results and showing all from the database. make sure I've added get().

Comment: yes, it was helpful. but now getting difficult to keep search results. after search results when you sort it result resetting and showing all data from database.